# How to properly write the function sequence $f_n(x)=x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.^{x}}}}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I express the following as a function sequence? Namely, how can I properly express $f_n(x)$?

Here are the following function graphs:

[image]

Text only (color-coded with image):

1. $\color{red}{f_1(x)=x^x}$
2. $\color{blue}{f_2(x)=x^{x^x}}$
3. $\color{green}{f_3(x)=x^{x^{x^x}}}$
4. $\color{purple}{f_4(x)=x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}}$
5. $\color{orange}{f_5(x)=x^{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}}}$
6. $f_6(x)=x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}}}$

So how may I express $f_n(x)$? e.g. $f_n(x)=x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.^{x}}}}}}$?

Comment: You can use Knuth's Up Arrow notation http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation is referred to as [tetration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).  Using your notation:
$$f_1(x) = ^2\!\!x$$
$$f_2(x) = ^3\!\!x$$
and so on.

Comment: So there is a special notation for that, after all. (Then again, mathematicians developed notation for virtually everything.) :)

Comment: By the way, is this function sequence considered "pointwise convergent" as $x \to 1$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  I suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty} \;^n\!\!1 = 1$, if that's what you are asking, so the limit does converge pointwise.  If you are asking if the limit function $f = \lim_{n\to\infty}  \;^n\!\!x$ is continuous at $x=1$, that's a bit trickier.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit rusty in this area (took an undergraduate measure theory class two years ago). I mean to ask if the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges pointwise to some limit function $\displaystyle f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$. I wasn't sure if there was such a limit function; I tried raising to another $x$ in the exponent each time, and the starting point of the function oscillates back and forth between $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: According to my [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Extension_to_infinite_heights) partway down, the limit converges for $e^{-e} \le x \le e^{\frac{1}{e}}$.

Answer (score 2):

$f_1(x) = x^x, \; f_n(x) = x^{\; f_{n-1}(x)}$

Comment: Can we only express this function sequence as a recursive one?

Comment: Well, addition is defined recursively as repeated succession, multiplication is defined recursively as repeated addition, and so forth. It makes sense to define tetration recursively in terms of exponentiation. Is there another equivalent description? I don't know. I cannot disprove the existence of such a description.

Comment: This reminds me of induction...